# How to pull the last 7 days from mysql database which includes count?

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

I am querying a table in mysql. At the moment the query works fine and counts the amount of repeated records which are in a table.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

Now I need to display that same count, but it needs to display only for the last 7 days. I have tried following and it does not works:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "' and  CompletedDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`

Comment: Can you share the table definition for `toutcome`?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Try using `NOW()` instead of `CURRDATE()` or as I am doing it, instead of `DATE_SUB()` I use pure math: `NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` or `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK`. Also if there is `DATETIME` stored in `CompletedDate` you might want to truncate the values to date only for comparison.

Comment: How does it "not work"?  The expression you have should work in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Daan and Gordon , both worked fine.